# How to ask cleartool lsvtree to show the author's name

Tags: clearcase

How to list the ClearCase versions including the author of each change ?

I tried `lsvtree -all` which doesn't give me this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the different options available with [`fmt_ccase`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-6-6), include "`%n %u`": `%u` is for user.

The doc mentions:

> Note: In commands that output data on multiple versions, such as `lshistory` and `lsvtree`, formatting is applied to each version, not to the command output as a whole.

However, since [`lsvtree`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvtree.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-29&lang=en) doesn't support `fmt`, you can fallback to [`lshistory`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-25&lang=en):

```
cleartool lshistory -fmt "%n %u\n" afile
```

Comment: Well, I was a bit too fast accepting the answer. With my PC `-fmt` isn't recognized. `$ cleartool lsvtree -fmt "%n %u\n" myfile
cleartool: Error: Unrecognized option "-fmt"
Usage: lsvtree -graphical [-all] [-nmerge] [-nco] pname ...
       lsvtree [-nrecurse] [-short] [-all] [-merge] [-nco] [-obsolete]
               [-branch branch-pname] pname ...`

Comment: @coin which version of ClearCase are you using?

Comment: @coin I have edited the answer to add link to the documentation and fallback to lshistory.

Comment: @coin ok. I suspect you could still use `lsvtree` by piping/xarg'ing its result to a `cleartool descr -fmt "%Vn %u\n"`, but check first with `lshistory`.